# Cannot use software-properties-qt

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to use software-properties-qt to change my gpu driver inio Nvidia's driver, but when I try appling changes, I got such an error:

```
pk-client-error-quark: E: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  libnvidia-cfg1-450 450.172.01-0ubuntu1 is not (yet) available (Could not connect to 192.168.1.18:7890 (192.168.1.18). - connect (113: No route to host))
```

192.168.1.18 used to be my proxy server, and now I don't use it any longer. But software-properties-qt still try to use it even I didn't set proxy. I tried google it but got nothing. I want to know how to clean the proxy setting.

Comment: Not just software-properties-qt but also include plasma-discover has the same problem

Comment: You need to deconfigure your proxy.  Check `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/conf.d/*` and others for proxy settings being configured.  It depends also on how you set up your proxy on system to begin with.

Comment: I have already checked them and I didn't find anything about proxy.